# Communicate iOS device with Virtual COM Port

Tags: ios, port

Our old system, windows application is connecting COM PORT to transfer the data to external device.

Now this windows application is migrated into iOS Application.

Is there any mechanism available to connect external device from iOS app via Virtual COM PORT

Comment: No, there is no serial port available on iOS without implementing hardware as a member of the MFi program  You could use a wifi to serial port adapter and send the data over tcp/ip

Comment: Yes @Paulw11, Please share any reference / link to achieve this.